# How to execute Multiple cucumber feature files using tags

Tags: cucumber, watir-webdriver

I am trying to run multiple feature file using tags, i have tried the command  cucumber --tag @some_name --tag @some_name1. But it throws an error which reads as follows,

"WARNING: cannot load such file -- 2.0/gherkin_lexer_en
Couldn't load 2.0/gherkin_lexer_en"

Can someone please tell me how to use tags to run multiple feature file.

Answer (score 19):

Example: Running scenarios which match @important **OR** @billing

```
cucumber --tags @billing,@important
```

Example: Running scenarios which match @important **AND** @billing

```
cucumber --tags @billing --tags @important
```

from: https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/api/#tags

Answer (score 12):

Try this to run multiple feature files using tags

```
cucumber --tags @some_name,@some_name1,@some_name3
```

Comment: Heaven forbid placing spaces after each comma!

Answer (score 3):

Here is the official documentation:
https://docs.cucumber.io/cucumber/api/#tags

Answer (score 2):

As `Eugene Snihovsky` said above, to run multiple tags, one at a time (not in parallel).

`"--tags=@create-case or @edit-case"` worked for me.

I am using VS Code to test cucumber, the full object I used to test within `launch.json` was as follows:

```
{
            "name": "Cucumber @create-case",
            "type": "node",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/tests/cucumberjs/node_modules/cucumber/bin/cucumber-js",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/tests/cucumberjs",
            "args": [
                "--tags=@create-case or @edit-case",
                "--format=node_modules/cucumber-pretty"
            ]
        }
```

As you can see, the `args` array stores the `--tags` arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me

```
cucumber --tags @some_name --tags @some_name1 --tags @some_name3
```

If you want to automate your test with [gulp-cucumber](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-cucumber)
there is a section **tags** in the config object, which takes an **array** of string tags

Comment: Hey! So I have a two scenarios marked with `@billing` `@important`, and I want only these two scenarios to run and hence I used `cucumber --tags @billing --tags @important` . 

When I run it, it doesnt recognize those tags, but when I run just one tag, it runs it. Any idea why

Answer (score 1):

cucumber --tags "@tag01 or @tag02"
that is in latest documentation and worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Running Multiple feature file, you need to add tagName into your selected feature file as

A first step to cover your feature file with tagName for example:-

```
@SmokeTestCases
Feature: Logout module
```

The second step to go to runner file and add tags into your CucumberOptions Example:-

```
@CucumberOptions(plugin = { "pretty" },
    features = { "features" },
    glue = { "stepdefs" },
    tags = { "@SmokeTestCases" })
```

Only those feature files run which is covered with "@SmokeTestCases" tagName

Answer (score -1):

This is for Java-Cucumber users :: Multiple Features are 1.Smoketest 2. Logintest Then your Junit runner java file should look like

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)    
@CucumberOptions 
(features = "src/test/java/testStep/",#Path for the Feature files Folder. Given you have smoke.feature and login.feature files present in the Path#
        plugin ={"pretty","html:reports/test-report"},#Path for the Reports Html Folder#
        tags= {"@smoke" ,"@login"})#Declaring multiple Feature names of files#
```

-- Cheers